# PHP sessions not persisting on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, session, amazon-ec2, persist

I am currently working on a Facebook application that runs on Amazon EC2. The app is working and most development is complete, however we cannot get sessions to persist. We have tried PHP default session handling, database handling and memcache handling using the PHP session save_path trick. We've tried messing with ini settings like auto_start, no avail.

The weird problem is that the initial session write DOES write, but any subsequent write after the first does not save. We can see the session cookie persisting, but the actual writing of data always fails after the first write. This weird problem applies to any session handler we use.

Our EC2 setup is as follows:

- Dev: 1 64bit linux server, 1 mongodb server, 1 elasticache cluster
- Staging: 1 64bit linux server, 1 mongodb server, 1 elasticache cluster
- Prod: 2 64bit linux servers with 1 load balancer, 3 mongodb servers with replicaset, 2 elastic ache clusters

The session problem is reproducable in all environments. I am running out of ideas here as I have tried everything I know and anything I found while Googling.

For reference we are using CakePHP 2.1, but have also tried sessions outside of CakePHP.

Comment: Can you post your simplest reproducible code? No one else seems to be having the same problem so it's likely to be something in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `session.save_path` in your php.ini.

Read this too: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Also, you may want to post all the session.* parts of your php.ini.

Comment: So found a few things after more debugging. I noticed that none of my ini settings were being written, and I later found out that the Facebook SDK starts the session automatically, which was causing CakePHP sessions to never be initialized. After moving some code around, my ini settings are now being written.

It seems to be working so far, but one small thing. I have the save_handler set to memcache, and I see the data being written, but they are written as <session_id>.lock and do not persist if I refresh the page, I get a whole new session ID each time. Only happening with memcache.